# MediaPlayer and returning to current activity via Intent

Tags: java, android

I'm using MediPlayer to stream internet radio, and have a notification display in the notification center when the stream is playing.

If I leave the app (i.e. via home button) and then return to the app with the notification (radio playing in background), I get a new activity where I am unable to then stop the music due to a new instance of MediaPlayer being created.

Is there any way to either stop all MediaPlayer instances or return to the current (active) activity?

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}


@Override 
protected void onResume() {
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
    }

    super.onResume();
}


//Display notification in notification center
public void showStatus () {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("RADIO")
            .setContentText("You're listening to RADIO");

    Intent resultIntent= new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(123, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you creating the instance of the `MediaPlayer`?

If you are doing so within the `Activity` then consider changing your strategy.

The right way to go about is to:

1. Create a `Service` that is in charge of instantiating and calling the methods on the `MediaPlayer`.
2. According to your application logic (i.e. wen a button is tapped) the `Activity` should post an `Intent` that will instruct the `Service` to do some operation over the `MediaPlayer`.
3. When you go out and back again to the app the 'Activity' wether it's a new instance or an old one - will post the `Intents` to the same instance of `Service` and thus to the same instance of a `MediaPlayer`.

For more details, you should check out Google's documentation on [Using a Service with MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices).

Comment: Fantastic thanks for the quick reply. This looks like it will do the trick. Thanks again